# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCint ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ld

I tried googling what this library belongs to but couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be related to the Cern 'ROOT' environment

```
$ apt-file search 'libCint.so'
libroot-core-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCint.so
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCint.so.5.34
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/root5.34/libCint.so
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/root5.34/libCint.so.5
libroot-core5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/root5.34/libCint.so.5.34
```

And from `apt-cache show libroot-core-dev`

```
Description-en_CA: Header files for ROOT
 The ROOT system provides a set of OO frameworks with all the functionality
 needed to handle and analyze large amounts of data efficiently.
 .
```